# How to change the frequency mode from month to date in Forecasting Arima model

Tags: python, time-series, jupyter-notebook, forecasting, arima

```
pred = results.get_prediction(start=pd.to_datetime('2019-02-28'), end=pd.to_datetime('2020-02-29'))
forecasted = pred.predicted_mean
print (forecasted)
```

**Output:**

```
2019-02-28    2140.581595
2019-03-31    2278.717662
2019-04-30    2040.213674
2019-05-31    1648.638694
2019-06-30    2004.805073
2019-07-31    1979.886953
2019-08-31    2254.028145
2019-09-30    2664.031189
2019-10-31    1915.292383
2019-11-30    2412.666350
2019-12-31    2020.935482
2020-01-31    2211.055072
2020-02-29    1911.809613
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

Here i got the monthly forecasted output. But i need forecasted output on daily basis.
I tried adding `freq = 'D'`in the `pred`. but i am getting the same output.

Comment: which module are you using ? statsmodels api or something else ?

Comment: @Vipluv  `from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA`

Comment: Is your original data set monthly resolved ? You could try providing the dataset in your question. get_prediction in statsmodels normally only predicts according to the frequency of your datetime sample